# Operator norm on the space on linear functions between Euclidean spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

*I'm reading a text which has a preliminary section on Linear maps. I have come across a conclusion that I can't seem prove by myself. *

> Let $Lin(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of linear functions
>   between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore let
>   $\mathbb{M}_{n,m}$ denote the vectorspace of $n\times m$ matrices.
>
> Then a sequence of linear maps $L_1,L_2,... \in
>  Lin(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ will converge to zero in the operator
>   norm if and only if the sequence of representing matrices
>   $A_1,A_2,...\in \mathbb{M}_{n,m}$ tend to zero in any norm on
>   $\mathbb{M}_{n,m}$.

How is this relation established? (Note that I am a topology rookie.)

Comment: I forgot to tell that i understand that every norm on $\mathbb{M}_{n,m}$ is equivalent.

Comment: In this case, you already have the answer.

Comment: @AlexM.  : Well let me further specify what i can't understand. How do I connect that when $||L_n|| = sup \{  ||L_n(x)|| | \, \, ||x||\leq 1 \} \to 0$ then $||A_n|| \to 0$. I cant seem to establish how convergence in two seemingly totally different spaces with different norm are connected.

Comment: The choice of a basis transforms an operator into a matrix. Therefore, with a choice of basis $Lin(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n)$ becomes isomorphic to $M_{m,n}$. Essentially they are the same space.

Comment: Let me make it even clearer: fix a basis in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and another one in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define a map $f$ that to every $L$ associates $A=f(L)$ the matrix of $L$ in the chosen bases. Show that $f$ is an isometry.